# Importing an Excel file into html? Possible?

Tags: html, css, excel

So I have a list with **a lot of items, with their name, description, etc** and I'm wondering if there's an option to get that list directly into an HTML file (more like instant into the tags) because now I have to copy-paste 1 item per item into the file and change

```
<div>
   <h3>Weight</h3>
   <h4>Points</h4>
   <h2>Title product</h2>
   <p>Info about the product</p>
   <a href="">Order</a> 
</div>
```

The list is around 200 items, so I have to change all these parameters above and copy paste them from the Excel into the HTML tags over and over. Is there any way to get an excel list into there? **Working with a database and php is no Bueno sadly** (project is too small to set all of this up for it).

Comment: You can save the Excel file as html. That way you can do all the formatting in Excel and it will be mirrored in HTML. Save as -> html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipting in excel or more easily the excel conntection to word. This function is called serial letters or something (sorry, my word is on german).

In word this function is mainly used to print multiple different labels or letters at once. But you can use this feature to create an automatic way to insert excel data in a textbase structure.

For e.g.

In your word file you will use some 'placeholders' which will be automaticly filled with the assigned excel row. After runnung you can just copy and paste this into your HTML file.

This ist what a possible world file could look like:

```
<div>
   <h3>[Weight]</h3>
   <h4>[Points]</h4>
   <h2>[Title]</h2>
   <p>[about]</p>
   <a href="">[order]</a> 
</div>
<div>
   <h3>[Weight]</h3>
   <h4>[Points]</h4>
   <h2>[Title]</h2>
   <p>[about]</p>
   <a href="">[order]</a> 
</div>
.
.
. and so on
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any tutorial (video) or (blog) post about this so I can see it visually what to do.

Comment: Because I don't know how it's called in english I just found a english/german solution. This may help you https://ms-office-training.de/en/create-series-letters-in-word-2016